# Миграция в БД С# Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Не получается произвести миграцию из модели в БД. Устанавливаю через `Nuget`

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
```

Потом в консоле пищу `Add-Migration Initial` и получаю ошибку

```
Startup project 'src\Store' is an ASP.NET Core or .NET Core project for Visual Studio 2015. This version of the Entity Framework Core Package Manager Console Tools doesn't support these types of projects.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.net core 1.1 изменил систему проектов с project.json на .cproj. Либо установите ef core старой версии, либо обновите .net core и переведите текущий проект на .cproj с помощью `dotnet migrate`

Comment: А можешь подсказать как это сделать? Я уже пробовал и обновлять все пакеты и использовать старые версии (но все не удачно). Как вместо net core 1.0.1 использовать net core 1.1? Так как dotnet migrate не помогает. Пишет, что такой команды не существует

Comment: @batya, удалить старый и установить новый https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core

Comment: Либо установить 2017 студию и при открытии проект автоматически обновится, но назад уже нельзя будет откатить.